# React class properties vs ES6 class properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React 16.2, class properties can be defined like this, see tagLine:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
 tagLine = "Super Hero";
 render() {
   ....
 }
}
```

However, in ES6 class, defining class property tagLine is not possible as shown below:

```
class Header {
  tagLine = "Super Hero";
}
```

Does React class has a special syntax which is different from ES6 class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React classes are standard ES6 classes. Class fields are a stage 3 proposal - [proposal-class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), and you need a transpiler ([babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)) to use it.

**Example:**

```js
class Header {
  tagLine = "Super Hero";
}

console.log(new Header());
```

Comment: React classes are not standard ES6 classes. They are an extremely special case of ES6 classes, having various lifecycle methods and differing implementation patterns. For example, [standard ES class inheritance is an antipattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) in React.

Comment: React's Component and PureComponent use standard class inheritance to extend the base react classes - `class C extends Component`. So React components are ES6 classes. However, inheritance chains - A extends B, which extends C, etc... are not a good thing. That's why React recommends not to continue the chain but use other patterns, such as composition or containment. This doesn't change the fact that components (expect for pure) are standard ES6 classes.